# How to get data as IEnumerable<MODEL> from DataTable by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with some *attributes* data get from a database, each data in that `DataTable` belong to a product, and each product could have more than one *attribute*.

So i have another `DataTable` which has all the products in a `foreach` by looping through each row i'm adding each product to it's `List<Plu>` like this:

```
var productAttr = new List<Plu.Attributi>();
foreach (DataRow rowPlu in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        int id = (int)rowPlu["ID_PLUREP"];
        plu.Add(new Plu(
            id,
            (string)rowPlu["CODICE_PRP"],
            (string)rowPlu[ESTESA],
            (string)rowPlu[DESCR], (float)rowPlu["PRE_PRP"],
            rowPlu.IsNull("IMG_IMG") ? null : (string)rowPlu["IMG_IMG"],
            productAttr,
            null,
            (int)rowPlu["ID_MENU_PRP"]
            ));
    }
    catch
    {
        return plu;
    }
}
```

For now the `productAttr` is empty but now i need to add to each product it's attributes, so with the following function i get a `DataTable` filled with data from database with all product attributes:

```
var attributi = Attributi(connection, idNegozio);
```

and then i was trying to do something like this inside the `foreach`

```
foreach (DataRow rowPlu in dt.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        int id = (int)rowPlu["ID_PLUREP"];
        plu.Add(new Plu(
            id,
            (string)rowPlu["CODICE_PRP"],
            (string)rowPlu[ESTESA],
            (string)rowPlu[DESCR], (float)rowPlu["PRE_PRP"],
            rowPlu.IsNull("IMG_IMG") ? null : (string)rowPlu["IMG_IMG"],
            from row in attributi.AsEnumerable() where row.Field<int>("ID_PLUREP_VAT") == id select row,
            null,
            (int)rowPlu["ID_MENU_PRP"]
            ));
    }
    catch
    {
        return plu;
    }
}
```

But the LINQ returns a `EnumerableRowCollection` while i need a `IEnumerable<Plu.Attribute>`, so i was wondering if there is a lazy way to cast the `.AsEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<Plu.Attrbute>`...

Comment: `.Cast<Plu.Attrbute>()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the DataTable only knows which values are in the cells. It does not know what these values stand for. It does not know that the number in column 0 is in fact an Id. It doesn't know that the string in column 1 is the Name of a Customer, and the DateTime in column 2 is the Birthday of the Customer.

If you will be using the contents of this Datatable (or similar DataTables) for other queries in the future, you need some translation from DataRow to the items that they stand for.

Once you've got the translation from DataRow to Plu, you can convert your DataTable to an `IEnumerable<Plu>`, and do other LINQ processing on it.

Usage will be like:

```
DataTable table = ...
var mySelectedData = table.AsEnumerable().ToPlus()
    .Where(plu => ...)
    .Select(plu => new {...})
    .ToList();
```

You need two extension methods: one that converts a DataRow to a Plu and one that converts a sequence of DataRows to a sequence of Plus. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static Plu ToPlu(this DataRow row)
{
    // TODO implement
}

public static IEnumerable<Plu> ToPlus(this IEnumerable<DataRow> dataRows)
{
     // TODO: exception if null dataRows

     return dataRows.Select(row => row.ToPlu());
}
```

If desired, create an extension method from DataTable to extract the Plus:

```
public static IEnumerable<Plu> ExtractPlus(this DataTable table)
{
    // TODO: exception if table null
    return table.AsEnumerable().ToPlus();
}
```

Usage:

```
DataTable table = ...
IEnumerable<Plu> plus = table.ExtractPlus();
```

I haven't got the faintest idea what a Plu is, and you forgot to mention the relevant properties of the Plu, so I'll give you an example of a table that contains Customers:

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}              // Id will be in column 0
    public string Name {get; set;}         // Name will be in column 1
    ...
}

public static Customer ToCustomer(this DataRow row)
{
    return new Customer
    {
        Id = (int)row[0],
        Name = (string)row[1],
    };
}
```

If desired, instead of columnIndex you can use the name of the column.

So by only creating a `ToPlu`, and a one-liner method to convert sequences of DataRows to a sequence of Plus, you've extended LINQ with your methods to read your tables.

To be on the safe side, consider creating an extension method that converts a sequence of Plus to a DataTable. This way, the layout of the table is in one location: `ToPlu(DataRow)` and `ToDataRow(Plu)`. Future changes in the table layout will be easier to manage, users of your DataTable will only think in sequences of Plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. If you want `IEnumerable<Plu>` you can remove the `.ToList()` from the end.

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Plu {
   Id = x.Field<int>("ID_PLUREP"),
   CodicePrep = x.Field<string>("CODICE_PRP"),
   ....
   Attributes = attributi.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(y => y.Field<int>("ID_PLUREP_VAT") == x.Field<int>("ID_PLUREP"))
                         .Select(z => new Attributi 
                                      {
                                        ....
                                      }).ToList(),
   ....
}).ToList();
```